# What is the formula to get the Interest percentage from Interest Rate?

Tags: united-states, calculation, apr

What is the formula to get the Interest percentage from Interest Rate?

Given :

Principal Amount : $1000
Interest Rate : $1 / Month
Number of payments : 10

What is the formula to fetch the percentage ? (APR %)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The monthly percentage rate is 0.1% ($1/$1000). The annualized percentage rate would then be that monthly rate compounded 12 times , or

```
(1 + 0.001 ^ 12) - 1 = 0.012 = 1.2%
```

More generally, the formula is

```
((1 + periodic_rate) ^ (periods_per_year) - 1)
```

Note that the fact that there are only 10 payments is irrelevant in calculating APR - only the periodic rate and the number of periods in a year matter.

Comment: Thank you, I am looking for the generic formula. Values i shared is only a sample. Having the formula plugged in a spreadsheet will help me to generate more details